# C++ Cout array values with upper and lower limits

Tags: c++

I have an array of prime numbers from 2 to 997. How do you display array values with upper and  lower limits? For example: 
Upper and lower limits: 0 20
Output:
2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19

Comment: Show us what you've got so far.

Comment: Many of us could write that code for you easily but what would you learn? You learn from toiling to solve the problem.

Comment: How do you know that `0 20` is the correct output? Why isn't it `0 21`? Or even `-42 42`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop on the array till you find a number bigger than the lower limit, Then loop and display until you find a number bigger than the upper limit.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out. I feel really dumb.